# How to create/append the Application folder name at the end of the Target/installation path

Tags: wix, wix3, windows-installer

I want to create/append the Application folder name at the end of the Target/installation path.

The default path is "C:\CompanyName\"
In this case also it should install in "C:\CompanyName\AppName"

And if the user changes the path to "C:\Test\" (by browse dialog or by typing in the text box), then installation should happen in the "C:\Test\AppName"

I've referred the Wix UI as "WixUI_InstallDir"

I've also Set the Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="APPPATH".

And my all shortcuts should point to the final installation path.

Sample snippet code:

Product.wxs

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
 <Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'>
    <!--- some code here --->
    <Property Id="APPPATH" Secure="yes"><![CDATA[C:\CompanyName]]></Property>
    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="APPPATH" />
    <Property Id="ALLUSERS">1</Property>

<!--- some code here --->
    <Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
        <Directory Id='ProgramFilesFolder' Name='PFiles'>
            <Directory Id='APPPATH' Name='Product_Title'>   
                  <Directory Id='ConfigurationId' Name='Configuration'>
            <!--- some code here --->
                    </Directory>        
                 </Directory>               
            </Directory>
        </Directory>

        <!--- some code here --->
     <UI Id="CustomWixUI_Mondo">
              <UIRef Id= "AppWixUI_InstallDir" /> 
              <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />                                              
    </UI>               


</Product>
```

AppWixUI_InstallDir.wxs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <UI Id="AppWixUI_InstallDir">

        <Property Id="DefaultUIFont" Value="WixUI_Font_Normal" />
        <Property Id="WixUI_Mode" Value="InstallDir" />

        <DialogRef Id="BrowseDlg" />
        <!-- some more code... .... -->

        <Publish Dialog="BrowseDlg" Control="OK" Event="DoAction" Value="WixUIValidatePath" Order="3">1</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="BrowseDlg" Control="OK" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="InvalidDirDlg" Order="4"><![CDATA[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID<>"1"]]></Publish>



        <Publish Dialog="AppInstallDirDlg" Control="InstallNoShield" Event="SetTargetPath" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="AppInstallDirDlg" Control="InstallNoShield" Event="DoAction" Value="WixUIValidatePath" Order="2">NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="AppInstallDirDlg" Control="InstallNoShield" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="InvalidDirDlg" Order="3"><![CDATA[NOT WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH AND WIXUI_INSTALLDIR_VALID<>"1"]]></Publish>            
        <Publish Dialog="AppInstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Property="_BrowseProperty" Value="[WIXUI_INSTALLDIR]" Order="1">1</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="AppInstallDirDlg" Control="ChangeFolder" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="BrowseDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>

        <!-- some more code... .... -->

    </UI>

    <UIRef Id="WixUI_Common" />
 </Fragment>
```

AppInstallDirDlg.wxs

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
 <Fragment>
    <UI>
        <Dialog Id="AppInstallDirDlg" Width="370" NoMinimize = "yes" Height="270" Title="InstallDirDlg_Title">


            <Control Id="InstallNoShield" Type="PushButton" ToolTip="Next" ElevationShield="no" X="4" Y="243" Width="80" Height="17" Default="yes" Hidden="yes" Disabled="yes" Text="Next">
                <Condition Action="show">NOT Installed </Condition>
                <Condition Action="enable">NOT Installed</Condition>
                <Condition Action="default">NOT Installed</Condition>
                <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return"><![CDATA[OutOfDiskSpace <> 1]]></Publish>
                <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfRbDiskDlg">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND (PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="P" OR NOT PROMPTROLLBACKCOST)</Publish>
                <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="D"</Publish>
                <Publish Event="EnableRollback" Value="False">OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="D"</Publish>
                <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="OutOfDiskDlg">(OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 1) OR (OutOfDiskSpace = 1 AND PROMPTROLLBACKCOST="F")</Publish>
            </Control>

            <!-- <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="4" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" ToolTip="Next" Default="yes" Text="Next" /> -->
            <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="246" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" ToolTip="Back" Text="Back" >
                <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="AppLicenseAgreementDlg">1</Publish>
            </Control>
            <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" ToolTip="Cancel" Cancel="yes" Text="Cancel">
                <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
            </Control>

            <Control Id="FolderLabel" Type="Text" X="20" Y="58" Width="290" Height="15" NoPrefix="yes" Text="InstallDirDlgFolderLabel" />
            <Control Id="Folder" Type="PathEdit" X="20" Y="75" Width="320" Height="18" Property="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Indirect="yes" />
            <Control Id="ChangeFolder" Type="PushButton" X="20" Y="96" Width="80" Height="17" ToolTip="Change Folder" Text="InstallDirDlgChange" />
            <Control Id="DiskUsage" Type="Text" X="20" Y="128" Width="290" Height="15" NoPrefix="yes" Text="InstallDirDlgDiskUsage" />
            <Control Id="VolumeList" Type="VolumeCostList" X="20" Y="145" Width="320" Height="75" Sunken="yes" Fixed="yes" Remote="yes" Text="DiskCostDlgVolumeList" />
        </Dialog>
      </UI>
   </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Any help please...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to show the folder MyApp in the dialogs, you can do the following:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="CompanyName">
        <Directory Id="MyApp" Name="MyApp" />
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```

And in your components replace INSTALLFOLDER with MyApp, this way:

```
<Component Id="Component_Core" Guid="*" Directory="MyApp">
```

As a side note, I don't recommend messing up with the dialogs just to show something like "C:\CompanyName\MyApp" or "C:\Temp\MyApp". It is easier if you just show "C:\CompanyName" or "C:\Temp" and install the files to the MyApp folder.

If you still want to show the full text, try something like this (**not recommended**):

```
<Property Id="INDIRECT_FOLDER" Value="MyApp" />

<Dialog Id="NewInstallDirDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.InstallDirDlg_Title)">
    <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)" />
    <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)" />
    <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)">
        <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
    </Control>

    <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="25" Y="23" Width="280" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.InstallDirDlgDescription)" />
    <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="200" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.InstallDirDlgTitle)" />
    <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.InstallDirDlgBannerBitmap)" />
    <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="0" />
    <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />

    <Control Id="FolderLabel" Type="Text" X="20" Y="60" Width="290" Height="30" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.InstallDirDlgFolderLabel)" />
    <Control Id="Folder" Type="PathEdit" X="20" Y="100" Width="320" Height="18" Property="INDIRECT_FOLDER" Indirect="yes" />
    <Control Id="ChangeFolder" Type="PushButton" X="20" Y="120" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.InstallDirDlgChange)" />
</Dialog>
```

Comment: thanks Marlos for the answer. Here I have couple of questions. 1) If we are using merge module (making it my heat command) for large section of files how to handle it. 2) And also if we are using WixLib (by using the heat command and lit command) how to handle? 3) Is all shortcuts will still point to the full installation path (i.e. C:/Temp/MyApp)?

Comment: 4) And also we have 3 applications, so it should point to appropriate application path example : If the user user installs the our 3 apps in C:/Temp locaiton, final installation path would be for App1:: "C:/Temp/MyApp1" and for "App2" :: "C:/Temp/MyApp2". so all my registry search (during install and uninstall and major upgrade should work for properly for each application).